# java Azure create table if not exists into table storage

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

Why do I get the following error when I try create table into table storage:

> com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: OK
>       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:87)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:209)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.QueryTableOperation.performRetrieve(QueryTableOperation.java:178)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableOperation.execute(TableOperation.java:694)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.CloudTable.exists(CloudTable.java:888)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.CloudTable.createIfNotExists(CloudTable.java:290)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.CloudTable.createIfNotExists(CloudTable.java:265)
>       at be.dela.gdprvault.test.StorageTestClient.getTableByName(StorageTestClient.groovy:25)
>       at be.dela.gdprvault.logging.entity.ActionLogSystemSpec.getActionLogFromTableByPartitionAndRowKey(ActionLogSystemSpec.groovy:114)
>       at be.dela.gdprvault.logging.entity.ActionLogSystemSpec.should save ActionLog entity to table storage(ActionLogSystemSpec.groovy:96)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableDeserializer.parseJsonEntity(TableDeserializer.java:290)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableDeserializer.parseSingleOpResponse(TableDeserializer.java:203)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.QueryTableOperation.parseResponse(QueryTableOperation.java:143)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.QueryTableOperation$1.postProcessResponse(QueryTableOperation.java:236)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.QueryTableOperation$1.postProcessResponse(QueryTableOperation.java:193)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:155)
>       ... 8 more

```
docer-compose
  azure-blob-storage:
    image: arafato/azurite
    ports:
      - "10000:10000"
      - "10002:10002"
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/opt/azurite/folder

    CloudTable table = tableClient.getTableReference(tableName)
    table.createIfNotExists() -- there is error
```

I did according the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-java

Comment: Did you verify that connection string is correct and create the `tableClient` properly?

Comment: Hi,please post your specific java code so that i could help you.

Comment: thank you, I've prepared code http://transfiles.ru/9jeo3. Run azure.storage.logging.entity.ActionLogSystemSpec. I try save complex class azure.storage.logging.entity.ActionLog, so I transform ActionLog to ActionLogWrapper

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your exception but failed. You could use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to catch the request and response of your java code to check the status code and error details.

You could refer to my working code:

```
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.*;

public class CreateTableTest {

    public static final String storageConnectionString =
            "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;" +
                    "AccountName=***;" +
                    "AccountKey=***;" +
                    "TableEndpoint=https://***.table.cosmosdb.azure.com:443/;" ;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try
        {
            // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
                    CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

            // Create the table client.
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.createCloudTableClient();

            // Create the table if it doesn't exist.
            String tableName = "people";
            CloudTable cloudTable = tableClient.getTableReference(tableName);
            cloudTable.createIfNotExists();

            System.out.println("Create Success...");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Output the stack trace.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

My sdk version is :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
   <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
   <version>8.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thank you, I've prepared code [link]transfiles.ru/9jeo3. Run azure.storage.logging.entity.ActionLogSystemSpec. It's integration test. I try save complex class azure.storage.logging.entity.ActionLog, so I transform ActionLog to ActionLogWrapper

Comment: So,in fact,it nothing with azure storage sdk itself,right?

Comment: my code work in production, but when I try write integration code, I gotten error. So I don't why it happened

Comment: @АлександрШинкевич It's hard to investigating issue if you do not share sample code in your question.

Comment: I also added the project to repository https://github.com/AlexandrShinkevich87/azure